# How to update variable in MVVM?

Tags: swift, mvvm

I am trying to use MVVM. I am going to `VC2` from `VC1`. I am updating the `viewModel.fromVC = 1`, but the value is not updating in the `VC2`.

Here is what I mean:

There is a `viewModel`, in it there is a `var fromVC = Int()`. Now, in `vc1`, I am calling the `viewModel` as

`let viewModel = viewModel()`.

Now, on the tap of button, I am updating the `viewModel.fromVC = 8`. And, moving to the next screen. In the next screen, when I print `fromVC` then I get the value as 0 instead of 8.

This is how the `VC2` looks like

```
class VC2 {

    let viewModel = viewModel()

    func abc() {
        print(viewModel.fromVC)
    }

}
```

Now, I am calling `abc()` in `viewDidLoad` and the `fromVC` is printed as 0 instead of 8. Any help?

Comment: You are creating new object of viewModel, that's why it wont reflect that value.When you are pushing viewcontroller pass variable that time.

Comment: How can I fetch the value from viewModel, without creating a new object?

Comment: add your code when you are pushing viewcontroller. you just need to do VC2.viewModel = self.model

Answer (score 0):

For the `MVVM` pattern you need to understand that it's a layer split in 2 different parts: Inputs & Outputs.

Int terms of inputs, your viewModel needs to catch every event from the viewController, and for the Outputs, this is the way were the viewModel will send data (correctly formatted) to the viewController.

So basically, if we have a viewController like this:

```
final class HomeViewController: UIViewController { 

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - View life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUp(_ sender: Any) {
         titleLabel.text = "toto"
    }
}
```

We need to extract the responsibilities to a viewModel, since the viewController is handling the touchUp event, and owning the data to bring to th label.

By Extracting this, you will keep the responsibility correctly decided and after all, you'll be able to test your viewModel correctly

So how to do it? Easy, let's take a look to our futur viewModel:

```
final class HomeViewModel {

    // MARK: - Private properties

    private let title: String

    // MARK: -  Initializer

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }

    // MARK: - Outputs

    var titleText: ((String) -> Void)?

    // MARK: - Inputs

    func viewDidLoad() {
        titleText?("")
    }

    func buttonDidPress() {
        titleText?(title)
    }
}
```

So now, by doing this, you are keeping safe the different responsibilities, let's see how to bind our viewModel to our previous viewController :

```
final class HomeViewController: UIViewController { 

    // MARK: - public var

    var viewModel: HomeViewModel!

    // MARK: - Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: - View life cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bind(to: viewModel)

        viewModel.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Private func

    private func bind(to viewModel: HomeViewModel) {
        viewModel.titleText = { [weak self] title in
            self?.titleLabel.text = title
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUp(_ sender: Any) {
         viewModel.buttonDidPress()
    }
}
```

So one thing is missing, you'll asking me "but how to initialise our viewModel inside the viewController?"

Basically you should once again extract responsibilities, you could have a `Screens` layer which would have the responsibility to create the view like this:

```
final class Screens {

    // MARK: - Properties

    private let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName, bundle: Bundle(for: Screens.self))


    // MARK: - Home View Controller

   func createHomeViewController(with title: String) -> HomeViewController {
        let viewModel = HomeViewModel(title: title)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! HomeViewController
        viewController.viewModel = viewModel
        return viewController
    }
}
```

And finally do something like this:

```
let screens = Screens()
let homeViewController = screens.createHomeViewController(with: "Toto")
```

But the main subject was to bring the possibility to test it correctly, so how to do it? very easy!

```
import XCTest
@testable import mvvmApp

final class HomeViewModelTests: XCTestCase {

    func testGivenAHomeViewModel_WhenViewDidLoad_titleLabelTextIsEmpty() {
        let viewModel = HomeViewModel(title: "toto")
        let expectation = self.expectation("Returned title")

        viewModel.titleText = { title in
            XCTAssertEqual(title, "")
            expectation.fulfill()
        }

        viewModel.viewDidLoad()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0, handler: nil)
    }

    func testGivenAHomeViewModel_WhenButtonDidPress_titleLabelTextIsCorrectlyReturned() {
        let viewModel = HomeViewModel(title: "toto")
        let expectation = self.expectation("Returned title")

        var counter = 0
        viewModel.titleText = { title in
            if counter == 1 {
                XCTAssertEqual(title, "toto")
                expectation.fulfill()
            }
            counter += 1
        }

        viewModel.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel.buttonDidPress()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1.0, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

And that's it